# Definitions of bubbles

Tags: risk, market, price, financial

In [Financial Bubbles: Mechanisms and Diagnostics](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2423790), Sornette and Cauwels define the concept of "bubble":

More technically, during a bubble phase, the price follows a faster-than-exponential power law growth process, often accompanied by log-periodic oscillations. This dynamic ends abruptly in a change of regime that may be a crash or a substantial correction. Because they leave such specific traces, bubbles may be recognised in advance, that is, before they burst.

I'm not an expert in the field but it seems to me that "bubble" is something that anyone defines different. Do you know any other definitions of bubbles?